# Textbox not populating the values based on Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform in which i am populating the data based on Unique ID's. I then want to give the users option to select the Unique ID through a Combo box. After that i want to populate the Company name pertaining to that Unique ID in the Text box. I am applying Vlookup for the same but it is giving me an error, "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the worksheet class function".

I have checked the values are there in the range but it is still giving me the same error.

Please help

```
Private Sub CBUniqueIDDSR_Change()
Me.TBParentCoDSR.Text = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CBUniqueIDDSR.Value, Lookup_Range, 
2, False)
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Application.Run "Before_Initializing"
Dim Lookup_Range As Range
sht2.Visible = True
sht3.Visible = True
Set Lookup_Range = sht3.Range("A:C")
With sht2
Me.CBMonth.List = .Range("X3", .Range("X3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBCustomerCat.List = .Range("B3", .Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBVertical.List = .Range("Y3", .Range("Y3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBOperatingLocState.List = .Range("C3", 
.Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBDecisionMakingUnit.List = .Range("A3", 
.Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBRelationshipBuild.List = .Range("E3", 
.Range("E3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBGiftAllowed.List = .Range("F3", .Range("F3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBDayDSR.List = .Range("I3", .Range("I3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBMonthDSR.List = .Range("J3", .Range("J3").End(xlDown)).Value
Me.CBYearDSR.List = .Range("K3", .Range("K3").End(xlDown)).Value
End With
With sht3
Me.CBUniqueIDDSR.List = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value
End With
sht2.Visible = False
sht3.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: where are you setting lookup_range?

Comment: I am setting it in the Form Initialize sub.

Comment: When you get the error, use the immediate window to check what VB thinks it's address is:  ? lookup_range.address

Comment: I am sorry i did not get it. Also i am getting the error on the Vlookup line. I tried replacing Lookup_Range by inputting sht2.Range("A:C") in the vlookup formula but it still gives an error

Comment: The error might mean that one or more datas in your lookup can not be evaluated. Maybee wrong sheet or wrong cell range or simple empty fields or you simply looks for something which is not in your lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Private Sub CBUniqueIDDSR_Change()

'If you Unique is in text format, use coding below
Me.TBParentCoDSR.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.CBUniqueIDDSR.Value, Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("A2:" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Address), 2, False)

'If you Unique is in number format, use coding below
'Me.TBParentCoDSR.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(Me.CBUniqueIDDSR.Value), Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("A2:" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Address), 2, False)


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("A2:" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Address)
    Me.CBUniqueIDDSR.AddItem cell.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, the above code works absolutely fine for me. However, it is still throwing an error when i use the Lookup_Range in the vlookup function instead of the directly giving the range. Any idea why and how to get over it if i need to set the range first and then use it in the vlookup function.

Comment: I have been able to get over this Lee. What I did was to set the lookup_range in the same sub of CBUniqueIDDSR_Change(). Thank you so much for your help.